# Animated elements cannot be clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just wondering if there was anything that I can do about this.
I have a working effect('transfer') animation which affect the transfer CSS and the element of where it's going. I really want the element of where its going to be clickable during and after the animation. Right now it is only clickable for after the animation.

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    @if ($stimuli['transfer'] == true)
        $("#sample").effect("transfer", {
            to: $("#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }}")
        }, 6500, function() {
            $('#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }}').append('<a href="response/{{$stimuli['sample'][0]}}"><div class="ui-effects-transfer"></div></a>');
            $('#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0]}}').css("border", "10px solid green");
            $('.ui-effects-transfer').effect("shake", 2000);
        });
});
```

What `stimuli['sample']` is is the following:

```
<td id="{{$stimuli['comparison'][0]}}"> 
    <a href='response/{{ $stimuli['comparison'][0]}}'>
        <img class='trial' src='{{ url('taskAssets/'.$stimuli['comparison'][0]) }}.jpg' />
    </a>
</td>
```

I am only able to click on it after the animation is done. I want to be able to click on it even during the animation. What can we do?

**Edit 1**
I have tried including:

```
$("#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }}").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "response/{{$stimuli['sample']}}";
});
```

This works but when the transfer class overlaps with the picture it stops working. I also tried adding this:

```
    $(".ui-effects-transfer").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "response/{{$stimuli['sample'][0]}}";
});
```

but since the class is not created before it starts it doesn't work. I've tried placing another div with the same class but hiding it with id, but still I can't click on that class.

I am trying to do what another user has done:
**EDIT**

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {



@if ($stimuli['transfer'] == true)
 $("#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }}").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "response/{{$stimuli['sample'][0]}}";
});   



$("#sample").effect("transfer", {to: $("#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }}")}, 6500, function () {

   $('#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }}').append('<a href="response/{{$stimuli['sample'][0]}}"><div class="ui-effects-transfer"></div></a>');

           $('#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0]}}').css("border", "10px solid green");

           $('#extraTransfer').hide();





}).on('click', function(){
        window.location.href = "response/{{$stimuli['sample'][0]}}";


});

    });
@endif
```

but that class ui-effects-transfer still

Comment: When elements are being animated, they are often wrapped in a `ui-effects-wrapper` div, so its possible depending on how you are attaching your click event that the selector will not match and trigger the click whilst the wrapper is in place.

Comment: so you're saying that if an element is being animated then the href might not function and I would need a javascript onClick?

Comment: I actually dont need the class for ui-effects-transfer to be clickable rather I'd prefer if it was just see thru so that I could click on things behind it. Any way to do this?

Comment: I tried this http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/VvJyJW?editors=001 just to make sure, and it looks like you CAN click animated elements

Comment: I tried this check my edits... But it seems a bit different with my transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method that can be used to make what is behind the element clickable is to use the following CSS.

```
  pointer-events: none;
```

This allows that you can click the picture that the transfer animation is going onto. Since we want to click on the picture despite the fact that the transfer picture is overlapping our picture we can use the simple css shown above in our ui-effects-transfer class.

Answer (score 0):

**in short term:** if you are cloning your objects dynamically then you can trigger your dynamically added objects click event by something like `$('.myDynamicObject').on('click',function() { ... })`

**Update :**

I didn't dig into your code. But I think (maybe) your selector is not working because the `"transfer"` effect is cloning your object internally and then does the animation effect... You can examine that by doing the following simple change :

change this line :

```
$("#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }}").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "response/{{$stimuli['sample']}}";
});
```

to

```
$("#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }}").on('click',function(){
    window.location.href = "response/{{$stimuli['sample']}}";
});
```

Hope this help. let me know if not, please.

**Update 2:**

In spite of your comments, it seems the `.ui-effects-transfer` is wrapping your object and your click event is not triggering. So please try this one :

for example if your object is inside a table with id='table1'. something like :

```
<table id='table1'>
.
.
.
<td id="{{$stimuli['comparison'][0]}}"> 
    <a href='response/{{ $stimuli['comparison'][0]}}'>
        <img class='trial' src='{{ url('taskAssets/'.$stimuli['comparison'][0]) }}.jpg' />
    </a>
</td>
.
.
.
</table>
```

then change

```
$("#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }}").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "response/{{$stimuli['sample']}}";
});
```

to

```
$( "#table1" ).on( "click", "#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }},.ui-effects-transfer", function() {
    window.location.href = "response/{{$stimuli['sample']}}";
});
```

if it fixed the problem. then take a look at http://api.jquery.com/on/

please update me.

Comment: How would i go about clining the element? See new edits

Comment: @JPFoster . I updated my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: I have tried that. I can click the picture. However, when the transfer element .ui-effects-transfer overlaps with the $stimuli['sample'] element then i cannot click on it anymore. Also the on('click' does not work when I put it on the .ui-effects-transfer element. I think because it's not created yet..

I tried placing the .on(click) attahced to the transfer effect or after with no difference.

Comment: I ever tried to use a setTimeout then to establish the on('click') but did not work either.